# Cannot find the JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a simple JDBC code.

```
static Connection c;
static PreparedStatement ps;

public static void initializeDB() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("dbconn.properties"));
    String connurl = prop.getProperty("connurl");
    String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
    String username = prop.getProperty("username");
    String password = prop.getProperty("password");
    System.out.println(driver); //prints "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    Class.forName(driver);
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(connurl, username, password);
```

1. But I'm getting

   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
       at testapp.DBUpdater.initializeDB(Testapp.java:71)
       at testapp.Testapp.main(Testapp.java:38)

The property values are perfectly accessed as seen from the print statement. When I replace the variables with the string values directly it works fine!!

1. When should I use

   prop.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("dbconn.properties")));
2. When I viewed the Driver class from the mysql-connector jar file, I was expecting to see some static code but didn't find anything.

Comment: Hint: You no longer need `Class.forName()` with modern JDBC drivers, since JDBC can now use the the [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) system for finding drivers ([more info here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)). You will still find the `forName()` call in many tutorials since it doesn't break anything.

Comment: When printing out a string for test, place characters such as "><" on either side of the string to be sure there are no blanks hiding there.  If you're getting the name printed "correctly", but the class is not found by forName, then the class is not found -- simple enough.  Has nothing to do with properties.

Comment: (And it should be pointed out that you're not using the result of Class.forName, and never creating an instance of it.)

Comment: (What do you mean by "static code" in question 3?)

Comment: Make sure your JDBC driver is in the classpath.

Comment: @HotLicks: that's actually the *propper* way of loading a JDBC driver (before JDBC 4.0, it's no longer necessary with a JDBC 4.0 driver), the driver class itself is supposed to register itself with the driver manager in a static initializer class, so no explizit instantiation was necessary.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: So I would find code in Driver class in any JDBC 3.0 driver?

Comment: @John: yes, pre-JDBC-4 drivers would need a static initializer block.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: still not able to figure out why this call fails

Comment: @John: did you try what Hot Licks suggested (find out if the property has no extra spaces anywhere)?

Comment: What do you mean by "static code" in question 3?

Comment: @JoachimSauer No extra spaces. btw i'm using netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the string has value `"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"` (note the double quotes) instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Remove those quotes and it should work.

Comment: touch down Mark. thanks, i'm still wondering why i gave those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to trim the values of the properties.
2. I would have load the properties in a static way.
3. I didn't understand why you had a look within this JAR...

**Example:**

```
class Database {

    private final static Properties properties;
    private static Connection c;
    private static PreparedStatement ps;

    static {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("dbconn.properties"));
    }

    public static void init() {
        String connurl = properties.getProperty("connurl").trim();
        String driver = properties.getProperty("driver").trim();
        String username = properties.getProperty("username").trim();
        String password = properties.getProperty("password").trim();
        Class.forName(driver);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(connurl, username, password);
    }

}
```

Comment: You normally do not need to instantiate the JDBC driver class.